# Custom Pagination for Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have to pull a report which uses `groupBy()` and so I am not using `paginate()` method in Laravel. I have created one manual pagination, which has the following code :

```
public static function getPaginatedResults($results, Request $request)
{
        $rows               = 2;
        $currentPage        = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
        $collection         = new Collection($results);
        $currentPageResults = $collection->slice($currentPage * $rows, $rows)->all();

        $paginatedResults   = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $currentPageResults,
            count($collection),
            $rows,
            ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);

        return $paginatedResults;
    }
```

This is working fine unless the next and previous URL. I am getting the next URL like `/?page=2` and it is not showing any previous URL. How can I get the complete URL here and I would like to attach the query string with the URL as I am passing `from` and `to` date along with the URL.

Comment: Well, if the next URL is `/?page=2`, there shouldn't be a previous URL isn't it?